# How to update graph based on calculated value from data in power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have been trying to create a graph where i need to put the percentage value based on the calculation being performed.

Input Data:

```html
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>S.No</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Terms</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Economic Times</td>
            <td>Basic Debt</td>
            <td>India</td>
            <td>215000</td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Economic Times</td>
            <td>Basic Credit</td>
            <td>India</td>
            <td>150000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>TOI</td>
            <td>Basic Credit</td>
            <td>India</td>
            <td>35617</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>TOI</td>
            <td>Basic Debt</td>
            <td>India</td>
            <td>85877</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Mint Today</td>
            <td>Basic Surplus</td>
            <td>India</td>
            <td>176500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Mint Today</td>
            <td>Basic Debt</td>
            <td>India</td>
            <td>387200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>Mint Today</td>
            <td>Basic Credit</td>
            <td>India</td>
            <td>215900</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>BBC</td>
            <td>Basic Surplus</td>
            <td>India</td>
            <td>18775</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>BBC</td>
            <td>Basic Debt</td>
            <td>India</td>
            <td>195000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>BBC</td>
            <td>Basic Credit</td>
            <td>India</td>
            <td>174220</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**For Eg:**  Need to pick Each category based on it we need to find percentage using (Basic Debt Value/Basic Credit Value)*100

For Economic Times we have 69.76%

We need to plot it on the Secondary Y Axis.

How we can perform the calculation in power BI and plot the line graph using the calculated percentage, Need suggestion how we can perform it or create a query

Comment: Please provide sample data as copiable text.

Comment: @David - I have attached the input data , We can copy the data from here , Please suggest

Comment: @Manz are you sure about "For Economic Times we have 69.76%" ? because 215000/150000 = 143%

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
Debt / Credit =
VAR _debt =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Table'[Value] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[Category ] ),
        'Table'[Terms ] = "Basic Debt"
    )
VAR _credit =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Table'[Value] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[Category ] ),
        'Table'[Terms ] = "Basic Credit"
    )
RETURN
    _debt / _credit
```